# How can I find length of json object in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
[{"FUNCTION_HIERARCHY_LEVEL":"1","FUNCTION_PRIMARY_INDICATOR":"1","FUNCTION_CODE":"16041049","FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION":"SERVICES","FUNCTION_GLOBAL_CODE":"163554","FUNCTION_GLOBAL_DESCRIPTION":"Internal Services","Function_TYPE":"bbcc","FUNCTION_TYPE_CODE":"ASSIGNED","FUNCTION_TYPE_DESCRIPTION":"Assigned to the Function"},{"FUNCTION_HIERARCHY_LEVEL":"2","FUNCTION_PRIMARY_INDICATOR":"1","FUNCTION_CODE":"16041049","FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION":"SERVICES","FUNCTION_GLOBAL_CODE":"1736","FUNCTION_GLOBAL_DESCRIPTION":"Information Technology","Function_TYPE":"bb","FUNCTION_TYPE_CODE":"ASSIGNED","FUNCTION_TYPE_DESCRIPTION":"Assigned to the Function"},{"FUNCTION_HIERARCHY_LEVEL":"1","FUNCTION_PRIMARY_INDICATOR":"1","FUNCTION_CODE":"16041049","FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION":"SERVICES","FUNCTION_GLOBAL_CODE":"163554","FUNCTION_GLOBAL_DESCRIPTION":"Internal Services","Function_TYPE":"bbcc","FUNCTION_TYPE_CODE":"HE","FUNCTION_TYPE_DESCRIPTION":"Client Service Function Assigned by HR"},{"FUNCTION_HIERARCHY_LEVEL":"2","FUNCTION_PRIMARY_INDICATOR":"1","FUNCTION_CODE":"16041049","FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION":"SERVICES","FUNCTION_GLOBAL_CODE":"1736","FUNCTION_GLOBAL_DESCRIPTION":"Information Technology","Function_TYPE":"bb","FUNCTION_TYPE_CODE":"HE","FUNCTION_TYPE_DESCRIPTION":"Client Service Function Assigned by HR"}]
```

How can I find the length of this json in SQL Server, if this value is stored in a json column in some table?

Comment: How should a length of a JSON object be defined?

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server has no `JSON` column datatype - JSON is stored inside `NVARCHAR` columns.

You can use `LEN(columnname)` on a column to get its length in **characters**, or 
`DATALENGTH(columnname)` to get its length in **bytes** (`NVARCHAR` stores each character as two bytes)

Of course, that just simply returns the length of the *string representation* of your JSON - if that's what your looking for. Otherwise you need to more clearly specify what it is you want to find out

Comment: Above example has 4 objects inside Json structure ? How can i get that value?

Comment: @SumeetSuman: you'd have to convert this string into a JSON object, and then somehow count its properties (and possibly subproperties). You **cannot** do this in T-SQL I'm afraid - you'll have to load that JSON into a language of your choice and do the calculation there

Comment: @marc_s ofc you can, using `CROSS APPLY` , `OPENJSON` etc